Cs01 computation for TRS with underlying single name bond
What’s the cs01 calculation formula for TRS with underlying bond for a single corporate issuer? Thanks in advance!

The simplest case - the mark to market of the TRS is the same as the underlying bond (dirty price, cum accrued), the funding leg and TRS seller's CVA adjustment are separate, then the CS01 is also the same as the bond. If you have a complicated model that combines the bond,  the funding, the TRS seller' credit risk, and its correlation to the bond's credit risk - you just perturb the credit spreads and reprice to get CS01s.
